# Textbox doesn't appear as it is supposed to be using bootstrap v4

Tags: html, textbox, bootstrap-4, label

I am using Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6. The textbox that is supposed to look like the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZyHC.png) doesn't appear the same when I tried to place one in my login form. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVKpg.png) is how it looks like in chrome. Refer the code below:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also there is another issue, the above code is supposed to place the label and textbox on same line but the textbox is placed below the label. I can't find any solution for this on the web.

Comment: Its working fine with `Bootstrap V4 alpha 6`  tested in chrome firefox and IE

Comment: seems like you forgot to add assets in your header or your custom styles overwriting bootstrap styles

Comment: I haven't added any custom styles yet. As I am a beginner in it, can you explain in detail about the assets part you mentioned.